# Calculate Decibel from Volume Level in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Can I get an instance of `MPMusicPlayerController` to `AvAudioPlayer` to get the sampling rate or decibel from iPod music player, or any property to get decibel from sound level?

Currently I am using this formula:

```
MPMusicPlayerController * player;
player =  [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
float soundValue = 100 * log10 (1-player.volume);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get decibel from sound level"?  If you mean the decibel of sound pressure level (ie physical volume) then no, because the dB SPL must be measured physically.  It will be different depending on the impedance of the speaker, the distance to the speaker, the efficiency of the amp, and many other physical things.  A decibel is a unit that measures something in relation to something else - it is a ratio.  So to what value are you comparing your decibel measurement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go ahead and assume that you want the dB level compared to 0dB (which would be full volume) because that's what it looks like your code is trying to do.  So for example, if the volume is turned down to 70% of max, it would be -3dB.  If that is what you're trying to do, here is the code for it:

```
float soundValue = 20 * log10( player.volume )
```

There's no need to subtract the volume from 1.  The volume is a float between 0.0 and 1.0 and essentially represents a percentage of the max volume of the audio.  Since it will always be either 100% or less, the dB value will be either 0 (for full volume) or negative.  A positive dB value would mean there is amplification taking place which isn't possible with simple playback.

By the way, according to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMusicPlayerController/volume), the MPMusicPlayerController volume method is deprecated in iOS 7.